# Create bucket in bucket Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way to create bucket in bucket? it will good for organize and manage files. If its not possible, i cant get the idea behind allow create many bucket just for set a retention policy. why that step not include in upload object API.

Appreciate any comments.

Paxton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot buckets with a bucket. Buckets are a flat repository of objects. However, objects' name can be constructed like directory path. It does not mean there is folders either in a bucket, but you can have a structure folder logic.

For example, I could store  files with objectKey(s), like this

```
MyFile.rvt
MyFolder/SecondFile.rvt
MyFolder/ThirdFile.xls
SecondFolder/SubFolder/MyOtherModel.rvt
etc...
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it will better if we have folder tree structure